# How to tell there's something wrong with the server during response that started as 200 OK. Fail gracefully

Tags: http

I am qurious if there is any standard method in HTTP 1.X protocol to tell there is a problem on the server during http response that started as 200 OK.

How to tell there's any error on the server if 200 OK header is already returned and we are currently sending the response body? In some standards-compilliant way.

**UPD** : There is a duplicate, but without a single answer (!) [HTTP: error during reply after 200 OK status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740429/http-error-during-reply-after-200-ok-status-code).

**To be specific**: I can not use `Content-Length` for checking at response end, because the length *can't* be known at response start.

Additionaly, I can't cache the whole response on the server before sending (because it is too big and I will run out of memory, and it's too long to generate so the user can't wait, etc...).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am assuming OP means "any situation in which the server cannot (continue to) send a correct answer to the client". One extreme example might be power loss at the server side.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I would not like to invent some "magic bytes sequence" and then escape the response body on server and unescape it on the client, unless there is no better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard method to do what you want.

To be precise, the standard method is to buffer the response on the server, then send a 200 OK and the Content-Length, followed by the content. As stated, this does not work for you.

The only alternative I can think of, is to wrap the content in some format that makes it discoverable whether it was sent correctly. For example, you might end it with a hash or even a digital signature. But obviously, such mechanisms are not part of the HTTP standard.